# transfer xml file to a URL using powershell script

Tags: xml, rest, powershell

I have an xml document that needs to be uploaded to a url for processing by the webservice, I have limited resources so I'll have to use a powershell script for this task, ver 1.
No, I cannot upgrade to 3 which I know has more tools for this type of job.

Basically I need to replicate this (Which works fine in linux)

```
curl -d @event1.xml URL -H 'Content-Type: text/xml'  -s
```

So far all I've been able to find is that I need to use `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` but using this is beyond me since I haven't been able to use it to get a response.

SO, is there a way to upload a text file using powershell? Or will I have to go about this another way completely?

Comment: [curl exists for Windows](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) (scroll to the bottom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a site to test with, but I guess you need something like this:

```
$req = New-Object System.Net.HttpWebRequest
$req.Method = "POST"
$req.ContentType = "text/xml"
$data = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\test.xml")
$req.ContentLength = $data.Length
$reqstream = $req.GetRequestStream()
$reqstream.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
$reqstream.Close()
```

If you need to catch the response, you will have to add that.

```
$res = $req.getresponse().getresponsestream()
```

++